# Encryption/Decryption with Twofish

Tags: java, encryption, twofish

I am trying encrypt and decrypt using TWOFISH.
I received the error: **Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: twofish KeyGenerator not available**

My code:

```
public class TWOFISH {

    public static byte[] encrypt(String toEncrypt, String key) throws Exception {
      // create a binary key from the argument key (seed)
      SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(key.getBytes());
      KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("twofish");
      kg.init(sr);
      SecretKey sk = kg.generateKey();

      // create an instance of cipher
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("twofish");

      // initialize the cipher with the key
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk);

      // enctypt!
      byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());

      return encrypted;
   }

   public static String decrypt(byte[] toDecrypt, String key) throws Exception {
      // create a binary key from the argument key (seed)
      SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(key.getBytes());
      KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("twofish");
      kg.init(sr);
      SecretKey sk = kg.generateKey();

      // do the decryption with that key
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("twofish");
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sk);
      byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(toDecrypt);

      return new String(decrypted);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Luk2302,  i know that algoritm exist, but i hear it today.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twofish

Comment: You can try from your side?
Example using key: dff60ebc093d5d12d90968cee4d55167 and text: 09/10/14 the enctrypted result to base64 should be: jqcPVMd5ykivknralaM0LA==

Answer (score 2):

```
KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance(String algorithm);
```

According to

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyGenerator

the accepted `String` value of the parameter `algorithm` does not include `"twofish"`, hence the exception.

Comment: @toto: There are numerous encryption algorithms out there in the world, the Oracle providers do not support them all, and they don't support TwoFish.